# Regex Match Everything up until removing trailing space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

`IF condition EQUALS value THEN do this`

I want to get the condition without any beginning or trailing spaces.  This is what I tried:

`/\b(IF)\b[\w\d\s]+?(?=EQUALS)(EQUALS)/g`

That almost works except for the condition has whitespace before and after it.

See a full example here: https://regex101.com/r/qsjlia/4

Comment: `\b(IF)\b\s+([\w\d\s]+?)\s+(EQUALS)`?

Comment: I'm trying to get better at regular expressions and want to do it as part of that

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/D6PAFT/1

Answer (score 1):

You can try below regex:

```
(?:^IF\s+)(\w+)(?=\s+EQUALS\s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/U94Q0L/2)

Answer (score 1):

In this proposed solution I've taken it a bit further by assuming that at some point you're going to want to have **Condition**, **Equals Clause**, **Value**, and both the **Then** & **Else**

## Description

This Regex

`IF\s+((?:(?!\s(?:NOT)?EQUALS\s).)*)\s+((?:NOT)?EQUALS)\s+((?:(?!\sTHEN\s).)*)\s+THEN\s+((?:(?!\sELSE\s).)*)\s+ELSE\s+(.*)`

[image]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

Will do the following:

- Pull out the Condition, Equal Clause, Value, Then, and Else phrases
- Store the captured characters into numbered capture groups.
- Ignore white space before and after each chunk of text

## Example

See also this [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/HgdIxc/2).

Given your sample text

```
IF 45 EQUALS 'Yes' THEN ASSIGN 28 ELSE SHOW 28 
IF factor EQUALS value THEN do this ELSE do something else. 
IF factor NOTEQUALS value THEN do this ELSE do something else. 
IF 2 NOTEQUALS 'Droids' THEN Not the droids you are looking for ELSE Found the droids
```

The regex will create the following capture groups:

- capture group 0 will get the entire line
- capture group 1 will get the `Condition`
- capture group 2 will get the `EQUALS` or `NOTEQUALS`
- capture group 3 will get the `Value`
- capture group 4 will get the `Then` block
- capture group 5 will get the `Else` block

With the following Matches:

```
[0][0] = IF 45 EQUALS 'Yes' THEN ASSIGN 28 ELSE SHOW 28
[0][1] = 45
[0][2] = EQUALS
[0][3] = 'Yes'
[0][4] = ASSIGN 28
[0][5] = SHOW 28

[1][0] = IF factor EQUALS value THEN do this ELSE do something else.
[1][1] = factor
[1][2] = EQUALS
[1][3] = value
[1][4] = do this
[1][5] = do something else.

[2][0] = IF factor NOTEQUALS value THEN do this ELSE do something else.
[2][1] = factor
[2][2] = NOTEQUALS
[2][3] = value
[2][4] = do this
[2][5] = do something else.

[3][0] = IF 2 NOTEQUALS 'Droids' THEN Found the droids ELSE not the droids you are looking for 
[3][1] = 2
[3][2] = NOTEQUALS
[3][3] = 'Droids'
[3][4] = Not the droids you are looking for 
[3][5] = Found the droids
```

## Short Explanation

Each of the capture groups uses this an advanced Regex construct to capture until it encounters a known block of characters.

From the above expression one of those contructs is `((?:(?!\sTHEN\s).)*)\s+THEN\s+`

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
(                        group and capture 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        THEN                     'THEN'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of capture group
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  THEN                     'THEN'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

## Detailed Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IF                       'IF'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                                 (matching the most amount
                                 possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          NOT                      'NOT'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        EQUALS                   'EQUALS'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      NOT                      'NOT'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    EQUALS                   'EQUALS'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        THEN                     'THEN'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  THEN                     'THEN'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ELSE                     'ELSE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ELSE                     'ELSE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
```